# How to specify react-router-dom routes in order for matching?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use react with following dependencies with the specified versions

```
{
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
}
```

and I want to have a route like this

- Home
- About
- Home/Test
- Home/Test/New <== this is my problem

I have

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <PublicRoute  component={Login} path="/" exact />
        <PublicRoute  component={Login} path="/login" exact />
        <PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path="/dashboard"/>
        <Route to="/404" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

On the dashboard I have this

```
<Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
        <Route path={`/dashboard/buyList`} component={BuyList} />
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/buyList/new' component={NewBuy} />
        <Route path={`/dashboard/buyList${ids.id}`} component={BuyInfo}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/showAddress' component={ShowAddress} exact/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/qrScanner' component={QrScanner} exact/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/productList' component={ProductList} exact/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/productListCode' component={ProductListCode} exact/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/deliveryScanner' component={DeliveryScanner} exact/>
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashboardDetail} exact/>
        <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

but in `"/dashboard/buyList/new"` is loading the component of `"/dashboard/buyList"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `exact` param to `/dashboard/buyList`

```
<Switch>
    <Route path= '/dashboard/buyList' component={BuyList} exact />
    <Route exact path='/dashboard/buyList/new' component={NewBuy} />
    //other routes
<Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

1. You need only one router, so remove the nested `Router` around the dashboard routes.
2. Adding the `exact` prop everywhere isn't a magic bullet. It won't necessarily solve your problem correctly here. The `Switch` component only renders the first match it finds, even if the one you really want to match and render is later in the "list". In this case "/dashboard/buyList" is less specific than "/dashboard/buyList/new" but because it's a prefix to the *actual* path "/dashboard/buyList/new" it is matched and rendered.

## Solution

Remove the extraneous `Router`. Ensure you've specified the route paths from most specific to least specific. If ordered correctly there is absolutely no need for the `exact` prop.

`"/dashboard/buyList/new"` is more specific than `"/dashboard/buyList${ids.id}"` is more specific than `"/dashboard/buyList"`, etc..

Also, remove the `path` prop from the 404 route so it can also be correctly matched and rendered in the case that no other routes above it match.

```
<Navbar />
<Switch>
  <Route path='/dashboard/buyList/new' component={NewBuy} />
  <Route path={`/dashboard/buyList${ids.id}`} component={BuyInfo} />
  <Route path='/dashboard/buyList' component={BuyList} />
  <Route path='/dashboard/showAddress' component={ShowAddress} />
  <Route path='/dashboard/qrScanner' component={QrScanner} />
  <Route path='/dashboard/productList' component={ProductList} />
  <Route path='/dashboard/productListCode' component={ProductListCode} />
  <Route path='/dashboard/deliveryScanner' component={DeliveryScanner} />
  <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashboardDetail} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```